# Number of research capsules

Tags: animation-throwdown

To get better cards we need to combine two cards to get a strong one using 2 machines in the research area.

Since level 1 we can research 2 cards at once because we have 2 machines. At the moment I'm level 10 and still have 2 machines.

However, as you can see in this picture's background, there are 4 capsules.

[image]

Is there any way to unlock the other 2 machines?

Will they unlock after you reach a specific level? If so, which level?

Comment: To date there is no way to unlock them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 2 slots for research, the other 2 are just an image.

Lots of people are asking to have more slots, however nothing from the developers at that moment.